# Weekly Schedule in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, grid

currently struggling with aligning items inside an CSS Grid item. The date needs to be in the top left and the "eat" in the top left as well as the sub at the bottom of the item - the Day 1 should stay centered.

[image]

I can only center the whole thing, but with position absolut the other text wanders to the bottom of the page instead of the parent grid span.

```css
plan {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 25vw;
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

plan-meal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

plan-meal > span{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0, 0.3);
  flex-direction:column;
}

plan-meal > span:hover{
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<plan>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 1</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Tue, 22. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 2</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Weg, 23. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 3</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Thu, 24. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 4</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Fri, 25. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 5</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Sat, 26. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 6</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Sun, 27. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 7</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Coconut Curry with green chillies</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Coconut Curry with green chillies</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Coconut Curry with green chillies</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
   <plan-meal style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <span>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Coconut Curry with green chillies</h1>
         <span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span>
      </span>
   </plan-meal>
</plan>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: You should only put phrasing content inside a `<span>` element and why are you using all the inline css?

Comment: To try it and see the difference. It should not be different - I have the CSS in its own file, but for testing I do it this way. Any idea?

Comment: I only now notice that `plan` and `plan-meal` are not html tags. I learnt a lot about how browsers render these elements, which apparently they do without complaining, so thank you for that. However, I would still advise against it unless you have a good reason for it. In my browser your code snippet is not rendered in three columns as in your picture, but rather as one column. not sure if you intended to have multiple columns or custom tags, but I will write an answer to consolidate my suggestions.

Comment: Thank you mrmonsieur! I did not include the responsive part, where I have the 7 or 5 column layout of the grid (I simply missed it, apologies). I will take a look at the solution, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.plan {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25vw) ;
  grid-auto-rows: 25vw;
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

.plan-meal {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.plan-meal > div {
  height: 25vw; 
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
}

.plan-meal > div > h1 {
  margin: 10vw auto; 
}

.plan-meal > div > p:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.plan-meal > div:hover {
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="plan">
   <div class="plan-meal" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <div>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 1</h1>
         <p><span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="plan-meal" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <div>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 1</h1>
         <p><span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="plan-meal" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <div>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 1</h1>
         <p><span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="plan-meal" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <div>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 1</h1>
         <p><span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="plan-meal" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <div>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 1</h1>
         <p><span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="plan-meal" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <div>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 1</h1>
         <p><span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="plan-meal" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/delicious-homemade-hamburger-and-french-fries-picture-id1254672762')">
      <div>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Mon, 21. Nov</p>
         <p style="color: #fff;font-size: 0.85vw;align-items: flex-end;">Eat</p>
         <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.5vw;line-height: 1.6vw;white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100%; text-align: center;">Day 1</h1>
         <p><span style="color: #fff;font-size: 1.2vw; white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; width:95%; text-align: center;">This is the sub</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Feel free to ask any questions about the alterations I made.